# MySQL: Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I tried to create a table in MySQL using the CREATE TABLE statement below:

```
CREATE TABLE `visit` (
  `visit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_visit_site` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`site_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I received this error:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'fooschema.visit' (errno: 121)

I used SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS command. This is the error message:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
140222  7:03:17 Error in foreign key constraint creation for table `fooschema`.`visit`.
A foreign key constraint of name `fooschema/FK_visit_site`
already exists. (Note that internally InnoDB adds 'databasename/'
in front of the user-defined constraint name).
Note that InnoDB's FOREIGN KEY system tables store
constraint names as case-insensitive, with the
MySQL standard latin1_swedish_ci collation. If you
create tables or databases whose names differ only in
the character case, then collisions in constraint
names can occur. Workaround: name your constraints
explicitly with unique names.
```

Then, I used the query below to list all available constraints:

```
select *
from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_schema = 'fooschema'
```

I didn't see any constraint with name 'FK_visit_site' in the result.

The FK_visit_site constraint was a foreign key constraint of table visit. I dropped the visit table and attempted to recreate it.

Is there a way I can drop this foreign key constraint even when the table it was associated to doesn't exist?

Comment: you could just give your new key a different name?

Comment: yes I could. But I would really like to use the old name. Using the old name is kind of important.

Comment: What does `select * from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_visit_site'` return`

Comment: too bad about the name. I would expect that the foreign key must be in there somewheres though..

Comment: select * from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_name = 'FK_visit_site' returned Empty set.

Comment: Key is already defined in another table. You must have to give new key name.

Comment: @Barmar: I did google the message, none like mine.

Comment: @Guatam: Then where is it? How can I find out which table and drop it?

Comment: Something I should mention is that the visit table has about 10M records in it. I executed this command:

ALTER TABLE visit ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_visit_site` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`site_id`)

and because it took a very long time to run I killed the process while it was running. So I suspected that the constraint name was created somewhere...

Comment: Try the query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121

Comment: @Barmar: The constraint name is not in the query result.

Answer (score 1):

your foreign key already exist , so either drop existed foreign key or rename your second key.

```
 ALTER TABLE `site` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_visit_site`;
```

or rename to other new one.

```
CREATE TABLE `visit` (
 `visit_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `FK_visit_site` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`site_id`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Added `PRIMARY KEY` to the `visit_id` line.

**Note:**

make sure that `site_id` in the `site` table have exact same datatype of `site_id` in visit table.

like that

```
  `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL  --//in the `site` table
```

> The two keys you're coupling must have the exact same datatype ( INT NOT NULL), even signedness

Comment: Having explicit constraint name is important in my case because I might need to drop it programmatically later.

Comment: Tried the edited version. Here's site table:

CREATE TABLE `site` (
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_site_location` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`location_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: try drop the `FK_visit_site` and then create it again in your table , just to make sure if it ecist.

Comment: dude your site_id datatype is not same in both tables. i have edited my answer craeted table.try it

Comment: I tried that. Here's the error message:

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'fooschema.visit' doesn't exist

Comment: hehe , have you created that table (visit)?

Comment: The datatypes are the same. They are both int(11).

Comment: No being able to create the visit table was my problem. I did create the visit table successfully. But then I dropped it and failed to recreate it using the same name for the foreign key constraint.

Comment: try drop that foreign key also . its in my answer.

Comment: Just tried 

ALTER TABLE `site` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_visit_site`;

Error: Cannot find constraint with given id "FK_visit_site"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you will get this error when you're trying to add a constraint with a name that's already used somewhere else. Means, in your case FK `FK_visit_site` had already been used before.

If the table you're trying to create includes a foreign key constraint, and you've provided your own name for that constraint, remember that it must be unique within the database.

You can run the below query to find out the same

```
SELECT
  constraint_name,
  table_name
FROM
  information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
  constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
  AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
  constraint_name;
```

Taken from the post here 
http://www.thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=81

Try using a different name for your FK like

```
CREATE TABLE `visit` (
  `visit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_visit_site_New` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) 
  REFERENCES `site` (`site_id`),
)
```

Comment: The constraint name is not in the result of the query you mentioned. I would have to keep the old name. My concern is if the name was used somewhere, where is it? Why can't I find it?

Comment: I saw your comment above that you aborted `add constraint`. are you still using the same session? Try running the query I have mentioned in a different session and see if you find it out.

Comment: Just tried the query in a new session. Still didn't see it. The foreign key was added to the visit table. Now that the visit table doesn't even exist. How does that foreign key still exist?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I have exactly the same situation. The FK is not in the schema but it wont create it.