# MYSQL script errno:121

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So i am using workbench to forward engineer some tables that i created , im new with mysql and i am having a problem finding the error in my code

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'mydb.pisubclass' (errno: 121)
 SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`PISubclass`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PISubclass` (
      `PISubID` INT NOT NULL,
      `PIID` INT NOT NULL,
      `FAID` INT NOT NULL,
      `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      INDEX `PIID_idx` (`PIID` ASC),
      INDEX `FAID_idx` (`FAID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `PIID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`PIID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`PolicyIndicators` (`PIID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `FAID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`FAID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`PolicyIndicators` (`FAID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

 SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

 Fetching back view definitions in final form.
 Nothing to fetch
```

Thanks :)!

Comment: can you `desc` your `PolicyIndicators` table?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121