# Error 1005, anyone can tell me what am I getting wrong?

Tags: mysql

I want to assign foreign key(email) references user(email), but It shows error. I cant figure out what is wrong.

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'schema.#sql-1bf8_f' (errno: 121)
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `schema`.`vendor_ambassador` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `email`
  FOREIGN KEY (`email`)
  REFERENCES `schema`.`user` (`email`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: This could be the same as <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121> .

Comment: You will get this message if you're trying to add a constraint with a name that's already used somewhere else. Can you check ?

Comment: Do you have create table `schema.user` first?

Answer (score 0):

I've have the same problem. These were my steps to resolve this problem:

1. Check if master table are created first.
2. Check the primary key on the master table are implemented and indexes are created.
3. Check data type within related column on master and detail table are same.
4. Ensure that column on foreign key in detail table are not set into primary key.
5. Check the foreign key or constraint name on other tables within database. The foreign key or constraint name should be unique.
6. If this doesn't help, check using MySQL Command: Show innodb engine status; to read the problems.

I hope this solves your problem.