# Mysql: No key names but Can't create table (errno: 121)

Tags: mysql

Yes, I have read all tpoics about [error 121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121) but I still get

```
Can't create table 'catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 121)
```

My query does not contain any CONSTRAINTs or key names

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_category_flat_store_1`;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_store_1` (
  `entity_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Renaming table does help but is not an option here (Don't like to rewrite Magento)

For `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I don't have the PROCESS privilege.

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0):

The query is valid, so can could be conflicting with another table's constraint name.  Try specifying the PK name via `CONSTRAINT`pk_id`PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_category_flat_store_1`;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_store_1` (
  `entity_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `pk_id` PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, try to run mysql with admin privileges and check if the user database has all privileges like drop, create, etc

Comment: DROP and CREATE works, but I don't have admin privileges.

Comment: Try to chage the name for primary key

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my innoDB is broken. I found my problem and a solution. Not done testing but looks promissing:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69656/cant-create-table-but-table-doesnt-exist