# errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update" when Create Table with CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I used following code to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE `Notes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `title` text,
  `content` text,
  `public` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `beerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `beerid` (`beerid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Notes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`beerid`) REFERENCES `Beers` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 87: Can't create table `beersafe`.`Notes`
>   (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

```
mysqladmin  Ver 9.1 Distrib 10.0.36-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Server version      10.0.36-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         17 hours 14 min 49 sec
```

(from Comments)

```
CREATE TABLE Beers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
    image text, 
    alcohol float DEFAULT NULL, 
    color varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
    category text, 
    description text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE Users (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    email text, 
    password text, 
    name text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

SELECT  *
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE  CONSTRAINT_NAME IN ('Notes_ibfk_1', 'Notes_ibfk_2');

| def | BeerSafe | Notes_ibfk_1 | BeerSafe | Notes | FOREIGN KEY |
| def | BeerSafe | Notes_ibfk_2 | BeerSafe | Notes | FOREIGN KEY |
```

Comment: can you paste the schema for `Beers` and `Users` ? You have duplicates in `beersafe` table

Comment: I guess you already have used those constraint names in some other table. Constraint names must be unique across all tables of your schema. Check for them: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME IN ('Notes_ibfk_1', 'Notes_ibfk_2');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121

Comment: @Mason.Chase 
CREATE TABLE `Beers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` text,
  `alcohol` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` text,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @Mason.Chase  CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` text,
  `password` text,
  `name` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @Bill Karwin 
> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME IN ('Notes_ibfk_1', 'Notes_ibfk_2');

| def                | BeerSafe          | Notes_ibfk_1    | BeerSafe     | Notes      | FOREIGN KEY     |
| def                | BeerSafe          | Notes_ibfk_2    | BeerSafe     | Notes      | FOREIGN KEY     |

Comment: That indicates you already have a tables called `Notes`. Are you sure your question describes what you're really doing? It seems you have created the table already, and you may be adding a constraint to the table using `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: @Bill Karwin
show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_beersafe |
+--------------------+
| Beers              |
| Users              |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the "write or update"???

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to create the table "Notes"

```
CREATE TABLE `Notes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `title` text,
  `content` text,
  `public` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `beerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `beerid` (`beerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

removed:

```
CONSTRAINT `Notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `Notes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`beerid`) REFERENCES `Beers` (`id`)
```